# pm2 process kill the server by running pm2 update multiple times

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, pm2

We stumbled upon a very strange problem while running any pm2 command. While running

```
pm2 list
```

we got this result inside console

```
[PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2
[PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized
```

but our pm2 log gives us more info about the error:

> PM2] Spawning PM2 daemon with pm2_home=/root/.pm2 2023-11-15T14:06:46:
> PM2 log:
> =============================================================================== 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started
> ---------------------------------------------------- 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: Time                 : Wed Nov 15 2023
> 14:06:46 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) 2023-11-15T14:06:46:
> PM2 log: PM2 version          : 5.3.0 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log:
> Node.js version      : 16.20.2 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: Current
> arch         : x64 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: PM2 home
> : /root/.pm2 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         :
> /root/.pm2/pm2.pid 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: RPC socket file
> : /root/.pm2/rpc.sock 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: BUS socket file
> : /root/.pm2/pub.sock 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: Application log
> path : /root/.pm2/logs 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: Worker Interval
> : 30000 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: Process dump file    :
> /root/.pm2/dump.pm2 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: Concurrent actions
> : 2 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
> 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log:
> =============================================================================== [PM2] PM2 Successfully daemonized 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log:
> =============================================================================== 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: --- PM2 global error caught
> --------------------------------------------------- 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log: Time                 : Wed Nov 15 2023
> 14:06:46 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time) 2023-11-15T14:06:46:
> PM2 error: Listen method has been called more than once without
> closing. 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 error: Error
> [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more than
> once without closing.
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
> at Server.listen (node:net:1550:11)
> at Server. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pm2-axon/lib/sockets/sock.js:408:21)
> at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Server.emit (node:domain:489:12)
> at Pipe.onconnection (node:net:1696:10)
> at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 log:
> =============================================================================== 2023-11-15T14:06:46: PM2 error: [PM2] Resurrecting PM2 Be sure to have
> the latest version by doing `npm install pm2@latest -g` before doing
> this procedure. node:net:1550
> throw new ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN();
> ^
>
> Error [ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN]: Listen method has been called more
> than once without closing.
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:387:5)
> at Server.listen (node:net:1550:11)
> at Server. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/node_modules/pm2-axon/lib/sockets/sock.js:408:21)
> at Server.emit (node:events:513:28)
> at Server.emit (node:domain:489:12)
> at Pipe.onconnection (node:net:1696:10)
> at Pipe.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {   code: 'ERR_SERVER_ALREADY_LISTEN' }

in the background pm2 runs dozen of this process

> node /usr/local/bin/pm2 update

which result in running server out of memory

Answer (score 1):

Try using below command options while starting pm2 process.

It will automatically restart pm2 according to adjusted RAM or Cron time

```
pm2 start app.js --max-memory-restart 1G

pm2 start app.js --cron-restart="0 12 * * *"
```